# 404 Page not found while deploying MicroStrategy Web sample

Tags: web-services, sdk, microstrategy

I am a newbie to MicroStrategy. I have managed to install MicroStrategy and Install the sample ([MSTR-SDK/samples/javaExternalSecuritySample](https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/931/docs/mergedProjects/websdk/topics/esm/External_Security_Sample_Application.htm)) in MicroStrategy Root directory /web aspx/plugin directory.

I am still getting below error when I launch the MicrosStrategy web tool.

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you browse to the file on your webserver at the location indicated (inetpub\wwwroot\plugins\ESM\JSP\mstrWeb.jsp) ?

Comment: I did. I did not find any plugin there. Actually plugins are placed in Microstrategy Install directory\plugins folder)

Comment: It's strange that your default install for your microstrategy website should be inetpub\wwwroot. It should be the microstrategy folder. Seems like there's something wrong with the install.